# c# - Why couldn't I access the comboBox in Winform?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winforms

The form1 has three comboboxes. In the form I tried to create the below code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<ComboBox> comboBoxes = new List<ComboBox>() 
    {
        combobox1,combobox2,combobox3
    };
}
```

I am getting the error like

```
A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property
```

But I can access these comboxes inside the function. I want to create the list of comboboxes. Tell me why I couldn't access it, and How to achieve this?

Comment: Fields are initialized before the class Constructor. Those references do not exist, yet. You could write `List<ComboBox> comboBoxes = new List<ComboBox>() { new ComboBox(), new ComboBox() };`. Not that useful, right? You should re-set those references anyway.

Comment: It is a language rule that was designed to keep you out of trouble.  Real trouble.  The .NET runtime doesn't actually support this kind of complex field initialization, the C# compiler solves it by moving the code to the constructor.  First thing that runs, before any code you'd write in the constructor (if any).  Problem is, the *combobox1* (etc) variable is not initialized yet and is still null.  The InitializeComponent() method runs later.  Workaround is simple, just move the assignment after the InitializeComponent() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Compiler Error CS0236](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0236): Instance fields cannot be used to initialize other instance fields outside a method.

You can initialize list in constructor after initializing controls:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        //...
        comboBoxes = new List<ComboBox>() { combobox1,combobox2,combobox3 };
    }
}
```

Comment: I am asking why I couldn't access it when I can access it in functions.

Comment: @prabhakaran because of compiler restrictions: `Instance fields cannot be used to initialize other instance fields outside a method`

Comment: There's no guarantee, that `combobox1, combobox2, combobox3` are *initialized* (since both `comboBoxes` and `combobox` will be initialized at the same time). That's why the compiler doesn't compile the code like this

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the controls in a method

```
        public List<ComboBox> comboBoxes = new List<ComboBox>()

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            comboBoxes.AddRange(new ComboBox[] {comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3});
        }
```